# Slider content appears for a second before initialization

Tags: javascript, css

I have a small issue that I hope you can help me with.
[My slider](http://12hrs.net/guides/12-hrs-in-antwerp/) shows the filenames short before the pictures are loaded (`image1.jpg, image2.jpg`).

I've tried to add following code into my CSS but without any luck:

```
    .slider > .rsContent {
display: none;
   }
```

Do you guys have any other idea how to get rid of it?

Here is the [documentation](http://help.dimsemenov.com/kb/royalslider-jquery-plugin-issues/slider-content-appears-for-a-second-before-initialization).

Comment: Try fixing the 64 errors and 84 warnings from the invalid HTML you have (http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2F12hrs.net%2Fguides%2F12-hrs-in-antwerp%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)

Comment: Look for posts about Flash Of Unstyled Content (FOUC). There's a lot of them :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your images tags are outside of your <HTML> tags. I don't know if that's unintentional, but I expect that's not helping. Move them in to your html and hide them with your CSS and move your stylesheet up as far as you can in the load order.

The is basically what is described in the two comments under your post. Doing both should fix it.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! I was forced to put the top-slider outside the loop/html in order to make it full-width. It's probably not the right way to do it but it was the only way I made it work. If it stays in the container, it get scaled down to 935px.

Comment: You could use absolute positioning to stop it from getting scaled. Your CSS should handle your presentation, your HTML is for structure.

Comment: That all makes sense. I've now put it inside the container but I just can't make it go full width. It seems like something is overwriting the css i'm attaching the slider.

Comment: The problem is that your slider has a width of 100% and is nested inside a containing div that has a width of 960px. You need to move it outside of that container or set the width of the slider explicitly.

Comment: Ha, I think it worked! I put it right outside the container but still inside the HTML.